# Text widget form and URL variables

Tags: urls, forms

I have an HTML form that I dropped into my Wordpress text widget that connects to a third party service so I need the form variables to be exactly right for it to work. The form is using GET rather than POST.

A select box I have is as follows:

```
<select name="a_mlsAreaMajor[]" id="IDX-a_mlsAreaMajor">
    <option value="DALLAS NORTHEAST (18)">Dallas Northeast (18)</option>
</select>
```

In the URL after submitting the form, it shows something like this

> a_mlsAreaMajor%5B%5D=DALLAS+NORTHEAST+%2818%29

I need the URL to read

> a_mlsAreaMajor[]=DALLAS+NORTHEAST+(18)

instead.. in order for the third party to process the form correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's a text widget, can't you just modify the text in the widgets text box? Without seeing the html it's impossible to advise on html changes

Comment: It seems to me your URL is correct. Its just encoded. Look at this reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @TomJNowell I included the select box that I have in the text widget for that purpose so readers could see the html that is the source.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes how do i prevent it from getting encoded?

Comment: Those URLs should be the same, I will use my own site to demonstrate: tomjn.com/?s=( vs tomjn.com/?s=%28 are both the same

Comment: As @TomJNowell pointed out, the encoded URL and the normal url should point to the same location and pass the parameters in the same way. It's like writing "á" and "&aacute;" in html (same result if the browser reads utf8). Your problem may be somewhere else. Can you tell us more about it?

Comment: While they should be the same, the remote service can tell the difference which doesn't support my theory, further investigation is needed. If the text widget does html encode its contents by default then this question is a useful and very pertinent one. If it doesn't then the issue is at the 3rd party service and this question is offtopic

Comment: Can we see the entirety of the text widgets contents?